# Why does my Netgear Smart Switch randomly untag VLAN on ports?

Tags: switch, vlan, voip, netgear

I have a NETGEAR 48-Port Gigabit PoE+ Smart Managed Pro Switch with 4 SFP Ports (GS752TPv2) that has been sporadically untagging a VLAN on ports. The VLAN in question is an Auto-VoIP VLAN. The workstation VLAN remains tagged on the same ports, and the workstations do receive a DHCP address and full network connectivity via Ethernet passthrough. The firmware of the switch is at the current release version 6.0.0.45.

I first noticed this on a single port a week ago, I re-tagged that VLAN on the port and everything seemed fine until today when a few ports were showing the same issue. I cannot reproduce the problem by rebooting the switch, it seems to just happen over time. Any ideas are appreciated.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

When using the Auto-VoIP feature of Netgear switches, ports should remain untagged for the Auto-VoIP VLAN. Instead, simply add the OUI (Organizationally Unique Identifier, the first three octets of the phone's MAC address) to the OUI table. The switch will automatically assign devices whose MAC address matches the OUI to the Auto-VoIP VLAN. Tagging the ports instead and omitting the OUI from the OUI table should work in theory alternatively, but for whatever reason it does not, and causes this issue sporadically over time.